# Google Cloud DataFlow Autoscaling not working

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a dataflow job that has 800K files to process. 
The job id is 2018-08-23_07_07_46-4958738268363865409.

It reports that it has successfully listed 800K files, but for some odd reason, the autoscaler only assigned 1 worker to it. Since it's processing rate is 2/sec, this is going to take a loooong time.
I didn't touch the default scaler settings which to my knowledge means it can scale freely up to 100 workers.
Why doesn't it scale?

Thanks,

Tomer

Update:
Following Neri's suggestion, I started a new job (id 2018-08-29_13_47_04-1454220104656653184) and set autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED even though according to the documentation it should default to that anyway. Same behavior. processing speed is at 1 element per second and I have only one worker.

[image: screenshot from web UI]

What's the use of running in the cloud if you cannot scale?

Comment: On Stackdriver Logging, what values do you see for autoscalingAlgorithm, numWorkers & maxNumWorkers?

Comment: In the worker startup: autoscalingAlgorithm=None. I found no entry in the logs for the DataFowStep with numWorkers / maxNumWorkers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to [autoscale your Dataflow Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling), be sure that you use autoscalingAlgorithm = THROUGHPUT_BASED.

If you use "autoscalingAlgorithm":"NONE", then your Dataflow Job will get stuck even if it could autoscale. Otherwise, you will need to specify the number of workers you want on numWorkers.

Also, to scale to the amount of workers you want, be sure to specify (for numWorkers and maxNumWorkers) a number equal or lower to your quota, check your quota by using:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```

Comment: What I don't understand is why it was set to None. I didn't set it explicitly. And according to the documentation, the default is THROUGHPUT_BASED

Comment: Hmm, that seems odd. According to documentation, for batch processes this only happens when you use earlier versions of the SDK. Are you using the latest SDK release (either for version 1 or version 2) and your job is not a streaming one?

Comment: SDK version is the latest (2.5.0) This is from the driver program log:
INFO:root:Downloading source distribtution of the SDK from PyPi
INFO:root:Executing command: ['python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '...', 'apache-beam==2.5.0', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']
Collecting apache-beam==2.5.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/96/56469c57cb043f36bfdd3786c463fbaeade1e8fcf0593ec7bc7f99e56d38/apache-beam-2.5.0.zip
  Saved c:\users\...\apache-beam-2.5.0.

Comment: The SDK version shouldn't be an issue, I see that your new job is using only one worker although it has the autoscaling algorithm setted. Is your job running in Batch Mode or Streaming Mode?

Comment: I think batch mode, but I really don't know. How would I know? I just followed the example here https://medium.com/google-cloud/python-development-environments-for-apache-beam-on-google-cloud-platform-b6f276b344df

Comment: If the PCollection is unbounded, then it will be streaming, otherwise it will be batch. You can easily check on the Console's Dataflow page: it will be either "batch" or "streaming" in the type section.